# How to create a WCS GetCapabilitiesType using Geotools?

Tags: java, geotools, wcs

I want to get the Capabilities of a WCS using Geotools (16.2) `net.opengis.wcs20.GetCapabilitiesType`. I found a [WCS 2.0 test class on GitHub](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/0e6fc022f395194e7670b63d2de785123a178cdf/modules/extension/xsd/xsd-wcs/src/test/java/org/geotools/wcs/v2_0/GetCapabilitiesTest.java) but was not able to use the code in the same way because this part:

```
GetCapabilitiesType caps = (GetCapabilitiesType) parser.parse(getClass()
                .getResourceAsStream(capRequestPath));
```

throws

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException  [...] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

I wrote this method to overcome the exception:

```
GetCapabilitiesType getCapabilitiesType(String capRequestPath)
        throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    Parser parser = new Parser(new WCSConfiguration());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(capRequestPath);
    GetCapabilitiesType capabilitiesType = (GetCapabilitiesType) parser.parse(fis);
    return capabilitiesType;
}
```

This throws

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   net.opengis.wcs20.GetCapabilitiesType

which I wasn't able to resolve. I also found a [WCS 1.1 test class on GitHub](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/0e6fc022f395194e7670b63d2de785123a178cdf/modules/extension/xsd/xsd-wcs/src/test/java/org/geotools/wcs/v1_1/GetCapabilitiesTest.java).

This approach works:

```
HashMap<String, Object> getCapabilitiesMap(String capRequestPath)
        throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    Parser parser = new Parser(new WCSConfiguration());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(capRequestPath);
    HashMap<String, Object> capabilitiesMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) parser.parse(fis);
    return capabilitiesMap;
}
```

but this way I do not have a `net.opengis.wcs20.GetCapabilitiesType` object.

Then I found the class `net.opengis.wcs20.impl.Wcs20FactoryImpl` [on GitHub](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/0e6fc022f395194e7670b63d2de785123a178cdf/modules/ogc/net.opengis.wcs/src/net/opengis/wcs20/impl/Wcs20FactoryImpl.java) which has a `createCapabilitiesType()` method to create a `net.opengis.wcs20.GetCapabilitiesType` object. I created my GetCapabilitiesType like this:

```
String wcsURL = "https://www.wcs.nrw.de/geobasis/wcs_nw_dgm";    
Wcs20Factory factory = Wcs20FactoryImpl.init();
GetCapabilitiesType wcsGetCapabilities = factory.createGetCapabilitiesType();
wcsGetCapabilities.setBaseUrl(wcsURL);
```

But when I want to use getters like:

```
List<String> versions = wcsGetCapabilities.getAcceptVersions().getVersion();
```

or

```
List<String> sections = wcsGetCapabilities.getSections().getSection();
```

they throw

> java.lang.NullPointerException

What is the best way to get a `net.opengis.wcs20.GetCapabilitiesType` object?

Answer (score 1):

When using your code I get an exception that the returned capabilities document is invalid.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    String baseurl = "https://www.wcs.nrw.de/geobasis/wcs_nw_dgm?service=wcs&request=getcapabilities";
    WCSTest me = new WCSTest();
    me.getCapabilitiesType(baseurl);

  }

  GetCapabilitiesType getCapabilitiesType(String capRequestPath)
      throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    Parser parser = new Parser(new WCSConfiguration());
    URL url = new URL(capRequestPath);
    GetCapabilitiesType capabilitiesType = (GetCapabilitiesType) parser.parse(url.openStream());
    return capabilitiesType;
  }
```

The "offending" line is, GeoTools feels that `simple` is invalid:

```
<ows:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.geobasis.nrw.de"/>
```

That seems to be a bug as that is a required type in an XLink `simpleLink` which is what an `OnlineResource` should be.

Comment: I got the exception (`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to net.opengis.wcs20.GetCapabilitiesType`) already before returning the `capabilitiesType` in this line: `GetCapabilitiesType capabilitiesType = (GetCapabilitiesType) parser.parse(url.openStream());`
Which line throws the invalid capabilities document exception? I will report the issue at OsGeo.